# GameObject LookAt not aligning properly

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, vector, coordinates

I have a celestial sphere with a plane in the centre and spheres (stars) aligned around the centre with a fixed radius.

[image: Celestial Sphere Screenshot]

In order to show the stars visible from a certain latitude and longitude from Earth, I need to rotate the plane accordingly.

To rotate the plane properly, I converted the latitude and longitude into 3D vectors, then utilised the `LookAt()` method to point the plane at this vector.

The following is the code which calculated the vectors from the coordinates, and utilises the `LookAt()` Method:

```
public void positionLand(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    double latitude_rad = (math.PI / 180) * latitude;
    double longitude_rad = (math.PI / 180) * longitude;

    Vector3 markerPositioning = new Vector3();
    markerPositioning.x = (float)-((math.cos(latitude_rad)) * (math.cos(longitude_rad)));
    markerPositioning.y = (float)((math.cos(latitude_rad)) * (math.sin(longitude_rad)));
    markerPositioning.z = (float)((math.sin(latitude_rad)));

    groundPlane.transform.LookAt(markerPositioning);
}
```

To test if this would work, I used the coordinates of London, UK, latitude: 51.509865 and longitude: -0.118092. And this was the result:

[image: London coordinates LookAt]

With the `LookAt()` method changed to the following: `groundPlane.transform.LookAt(markerPositioning, Vector3.forward);`

This is the result:

[image: Vector3.forward]

Replacing `groundPlane.transform.LookAt(markerPositioning);` with `groundPlane.transform.up = markerPositioning;` results in the following:

[image]

As you can see, the plane is not properly rotating. Initially, I thought maybe the `LookAt()` method is using the incorrect forward vector of the plane gameobject, but this isn't the case as there is no connection between the way the plane rotated and the coordinates of London as the plane is near vertical at 89 degrees.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Remember a plane's forward vector lies in the plane, not perpendicular to it. So when calling LookAt you're pointing part of the horizon at your chosen point, which is the opposite of what you want to do. You want to point the plane normal at your chosen point in the celestial sphere, so that the horizon traces out a great circle perpendicular to this direction.

Comment: Does this mean I have to compensate by subtracting the Z-axis rotation by the latitude value in degrees?

Comment: Have you considered `groundPlane.transform.up = markerPositioning;`?

Comment: I have tried this, this sets the groundPlane rotation to X:51.51, Y:51.60, Z:90.12. This doesn't seem correct as the groundPlane object is positioned vertically. See the edit to the original question to see what this looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spherical coordinate functions are written for a z-up coordinate system. Unity is a y-up coordinate system.

You want something more like this (assuming the prime meridian faces z+):

```
normal.x = - Mathf.Cos(latitude_rad) * Mathf.Sin(longitude_rad);
normal.y =   Mathf.Sin(latitude_rad);
normal.z =   Mathf.Cos(latitude_rad) * Mathf.Cos(longitude_rad);

transform.up = normal;
```

Or, as a one-liner, letting Unity handle the trig for you:

```
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90f - latitude_deg, -longitude_deg, 0);
```

Comment: Say if I want to remove the negative sign from the x-axis, how can I change the one-liner to reflect this?

Comment: It depends what you mean geometrically by "remove the negative sign from the x-axis". Can you describe what you want to change about the net rotation?

Comment: initially, I had included the negative sign in the x-axis calculation to mirror everything in the x-axis. Am I right to think this?

Comment: Also, I can confirm that this code works. I only activated the stars in the Scorpius constellation and compared the layout with that from another stargazing app called Stellarium. The constellation was align properly

Comment: Does that mean you don't need to apply additional mirroring to the code above? Or are you still looking to mirror the longitude?

Comment: I’ve managed to mirror it using the longer code, how can I achieve this from the one-liner code?

Comment: Presumably you considered negating the longitude variable?

Comment: Yup just did, thank you so much!